# How to add event onClick in dynamic template Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, templates

I want to add event onclick into button template like below, please help!

```
`<button @click="onShowPage()"><img style="width:${iconSize}; height:${iconSize}" src="/common/img/icon-video.png" /></button>`
```

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: @nam.dang You have to describe more details about the issue/question you have.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button @click="onShowPage()"><img :style="'width:'+ iconSize +'; height:'+ iconSize + ';'" src="/common/img/icon-video.png" /></button>
```

How about this?